# Note Taking App That Opens With a Hotkey & Reports Time Spent on Tagged Notes

Tags: note-taking

What I'd like:

OS: Mac

Features:

- GUI app that's brought up with hotkeys and exited with esc or enter

  - Prefer just a box big enough to show an entry, entries, or reports
- Press Command + Key brings up a prompt & creates a new entry

  - Entry comes pre-entered with a timestamp
  - Ability to type in some notes, press enter, entry goes away and is stored
- Plaintext storage (what I enter is what I get)
- Ability to add [tag]s to each entry
- Tracks time spent on each [tag] based on timestamps
- Command + Key hotkey to bring up report on amount of time spent on each [tag]
- Command + Key Viewing notes (read only)

Budget: $100

Edit1: Added stuff from [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Could you give additional details of software that you need? It seems too abroad. You can give us information like the required operating system, paid or free software. Please, refer to this guide http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information